# Grab everything between multiple brackets ([])

Tags: java, regex

I'm struggling to get a regex string working to where I can grab the groups and see if they equal a specific string.

My goal;

String I'm using:

```
[TEXT]&8/&7Nations create &8[&aName&8][/TEXT][HOVER]&7Click to run this command.[/HOVER][SUGGEST]/nations create [/SUGGEST]
```

I want to grab [TEXT][/TEXT] [HOVER][/HOVER] [SUGGEST][/SUGGEST] and everything in-between them. Each string inbetween them will do something different.

As you notice, the text in-between can contain [] also. I do not want to grab these. only the placeholders I listed above.

Only regex patterns I've came up with so far;

```
\[([^\[\]]|)*\]
\[(.+?)]([^]\]].+)\[(.+?)]
\[(.+?)](.+)\[(.+?)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a working solution by using matching numbered captured group in regex. Here is the working regex:
`\[([^\]]+)\](.*)\[(\/\1)\]`

#### Explanation

1. `\[` matches the character [ literally (case sensitive)
2. `([^\]]+)` 1st Capturing Group

   - `[^\]]+` Match a single character not present in the list below

     - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
     - `\]` matches the character ] literally (case sensitive)
3. `\]` matches the character ] literally (case sensitive)
4. `(.*)` 2nd Capturing Group

   - `.*` matches any character (except for line terminators)
   - `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
5. `\[` matches the character [ literally (case sensitive)
6. `(\/\1)` 3rd Capturing Group

   - `\/` matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
   - `\1` matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group (see above)
7. `\]` matches the character ] literally (case sensitive)

In your example, parts 1-2-3 match to `[TEXT]`, `[HOVER]` OR `[SUGGEST]`, part 5-6-7 match to respective closing tags `[/TEXT]`, `[/HOVER]` OR `[/SUGGEST]` and part 4 matches text in between opening and closing tag pairs.

```
[TEXT]&8/&7Nations create &8[&aName&8][/TEXT][HOVER]&7Click to run this command.[/HOVER][SUGGEST]/nations create [/SUGGEST]

Match 1
Full match  [TEXT]&8/&7Nations create &8[&aName&8][/TEXT]
Group 1.    TEXT
Group 2.    &8/&7Nations create &8[&aName&8]
Group 3.    /TEXT

Match 2
Full match  [HOVER]&7Click to run this command.[/HOVER]
Group 1.    HOVER
Group 2.    &7Click to run this command.
Group 3.    /HOVER

Match 3
Full match  [SUGGEST]/nations create [/SUGGEST]
Group 1.    SUGGEST
Group 2.    /nations create 
Group 3.    /SUGGEST
```

#### Reference

Please refer your example in working state on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/yc2ssv/1).

---

If you don't want to have any tags supported by your regex but just need `[TEXT][/TEXT]`, `[HOVER][/HOVER]` and `[SUGGEST][/SUGGEST]`, below regex should work fine:  `\[(TEXT|HOVER|SUGGEST)\](.*)\[(\/\1)\]`